# Set Shape Key values based on active key

Tags: shape-keys

I need to set the shape key values of an object, so that when I select a shape key in my UI list (and it becomes the active key) it's value is automatically set to 1, and at the same time every other shape key is set to 0.

Anyone any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

sound like you have this pin icon enabled:
 [image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)